# Alternative of RDP wrapper

Tags: windows, rdp

A few days ago GitHub disabled the RDP wrapper repository, and RDP wrapper is not compatible with windows 10 latest builds.
Any alternative application which will work with windows 10 latest builds.
It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repository and StasCorp account are back again
https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/releases

Comment: This is not supported by windows 10.

Comment: It works in Windows 10, too.

Comment: https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/1244